# Interlocked functions in Haxe

Tags: haxe, ref, interlocked

I am new to Haxe.

When I try to convert the following line from C# to Haxe using CS2HX:

`Interlocked.Increment(ref this.fieldName);`

I get error from CS2HX:

`ref/out cannot reference fields, only local variables`

Now this makes me wonder - are **Interlocked** functions at all supported by **Haxe** - ? 

Since I certainly would want to use Interlocked on fields and not on local variables.

Are there any alternative options besides using a **lock**?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge of C# to answer your question, but there would be people on the Haxe mailing list who could.  Maybe worth asking there? http://groups.google.com/group/haxelang?hl=en

Comment: Where do you get this error? Is it on the Haxe compiler or on CS2HX?

Comment: @Waneck: Thanks for the clarification, the error comes from CS2HX.

Comment: @JasonO'Neil - thanks, I posted the question to Google Groups. If something comes from it, I will add reference to it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haxe should now have support for ref/out arguments extended so that fields are accepted too. The updates are in Git. Thanks go to @Waneck!

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/haxelang/3E-N93qoU38

CS2HX needs separate modification for that upgrade. 
Maybe I will do that later myself, at the moment I have no time for that. I will post a comment here when I have updated CS2HX myself or find out that somebody else did it.

An alternative idea that came from that forum is using one-element array, I think that is pretty good too. Certainly better than using locks.